# Read (audio) file from subfolder in AndroidAssets in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-assets

I try to eneable audio in my Xamarin.Forms application. I want to have the audio files in a `Subfolder`of the `Assets`folder like this `Assets/Subfolder/Audio.mp3`

I have found a plugin [SimpleAudioPlayer](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/master/SimpleAudioPlayer) which provide an example. 
The following code works like provided.

```
var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
player.Load("Audio.mp3");
```

Now I want to place the audio file in a subfolder and I tried to call

```
player.Load("Subfolder/Audio.mp3");
```

But I get an `Java.IO.FileNotFoundException`
I looked then into the [implementation of the Load function](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/blob/master/SimpleAudioPlayer/SimpleAudioPlayer/Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.Android/SimpleAudioPlayerImplementation.cs) and I fould the following code

```
public bool Load(string fileName)
{
    player.Reset();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
    player?.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);
    return PreparePlayer();
}
```

where the `filename` is pasted to the `Assets.OpenFd()` function. which returns an `AndroidFileDesriptor`
The documentation does not really provide any information from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) and from the [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) site. 
My questions are

1. How can I receive the file from the subfolder in Android Assets?
2. What can I paste into the Assets.OpenFd() function (subfolders etc)?

I would appreciate any advice, since after a long time trying to resolve it I don't really have an idea.

Comment: In general it works at once. I don't know why. Everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of the package, you won't be able to do just that because you have to use `player.Load(GetStreamFromFile("mysound.wav"));` where `GetStreamFromFile` is basically

```
Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
{
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App." + filename); 
    // Obviously App in the line above should be replaced with your app
    return stream;
}
```

And secondly you have to `player.Load(GetStreamFromFile("Subfolder.mysound.wav"));` where `Subfolder` is the name of your subfolder.